# Arduino Java Serial Port gnu.io.NoSuchPortException

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, arduino-ide, jarduino

I am using serial port JAVA to Arduino.. But i get this error when i run the program.What is the my fault i am going to add Serial.dll and paralel.dll on this way C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin but i dont know where is my fault..

> Load RxTx Windows 10 WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
>
> Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
>
> native lib Version = RXTX-2.2-20081207 Cloudhopper Build 
>   rxtx.cloudhopper.net
>
> gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
>
> at
>   gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(CommPortIdentifier.java:269)
>
> at
>   org.sintef.jarduino.comm.Serial4JArduino.connect(Serial4JArduino.java:88)
>
> at
>   org.sintef.jarduino.comm.Serial4JArduino.(Serial4JArduino.java:82)
>
> at
>   org.sintef.jarduino.AbstractJArduino.(AbstractJArduino.java:30)
>
> at org.sintef.jarduino.JArduino.(JArduino.java:45)
>
> at Arduino.ArduinoServer.(ArduinoServer.java:25)
>
> at Arduino.ArduinoServer.main(ArduinoServer.java:37)
>
> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at
>   org.sintef.jarduino.comm.Serial4JArduino.sendData(Serial4JArduino.java:155)
>
> at
>   org.sintef.jarduino.comm.Serial4JArduino.receiveMsg(Serial4JArduino.java:129)
>
> at
>   org.sintef.jarduino.AbstractJArduino.pinMode(AbstractJArduino.java:42)
>
> at Arduino.ArduinoServer.setup(ArduinoServer.java:85)
>
> at
>   org.sintef.jarduino.JArduino$RemoteArduinoProcess.run(JArduino.java:101)

**EDİTTED CODE**

```
package Arduino;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.sintef.jarduino.DigitalPin;
import org.sintef.jarduino.DigitalState;
import org.sintef.jarduino.JArduino;
import org.sintef.jarduino.PinMode;


public class ArduinoServer  extends JArduino{

    public ArduinoServer(String port) {
        super(port);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    static int LedParlakligi=0;
    public static void main(String[] Args)
    {

        String serialPort;

        serialPort = "COM5";

    JArduino arduino = new ArduinoServer(serialPort);
    arduino.runArduinoProcess();


    }
    @Override
    protected void loop() {

        digitalWrite(DigitalPin.PIN_9, DigitalState.fromValue((byte) 55));
        delay(50); // wait for a second

    }
    @Override
    protected void setup() {
        // initialize the digital pin as an output.
        // Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards:
        pinMode(DigitalPin.PIN_9, PinMode.OUTPUT);

    }


}
```

I am going to try 2 way about SerialPort 
first is SerialPort = "5";
Second is SerialPort="COM5";

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I added sir @ToddSewell

Comment: And `COM5` is indeed the port displayed on the bottom right of the Arduino IDE?

Comment: Yes the port is right @ToddSewell